# Can't segue between 2 Table View Controllers

Tags: objective-c, ios, uitableview

I have a TableView with sections in it. I've connected a push segue between the cell of the first table view to another table view but when I push the cell nothing happens. I tried to do something like this:

```
- (void)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView didSelectRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
    NSLog(@"ROW: %d",indexPath.row);
    [self performSegueWithIdentifier:@"mySegue" sender:self];
        NSLog(@"ROW2: %d",indexPath.row);
}
```

I can see the rows are detected but still, there's no push from one vc to another.

Comment: Despite the fact that you don't need to do that when you defined it properly in IB/Storyboard, ... Is the spelling of "mySegue" correct? It is case sensitive!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You don't have to call `performSegueWithIdentifier:`, if the segue in the Storyboard is between the cell and the next TableViewController. It is done automatically. Make sure you draged the segue from the cell, and not from the View Controller.